# How to Implement Excel COMBIN function in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures

How can i implement Excel COMBIN function in SQL 2005, either in a store procedure or in a function. About COMBIN function in Excel follow this [Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052090181033.aspx).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Either implement a factorial function or depending on your possible input range, store factorial results in a table.
2. Implement the formula, as seen in your link.

Answer (score 1):

No built-in method for doing this, you will have to make a custom user-defined function.

Rather than doing something crazy like a recursively factorial (as seen in [this forum discussion](http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/20553/115111.aspx)), I would do the following:

- Create a factorial lookup table, holding pre-calculated factorial values (maybe 1! to 100!, since 100! is over 9.3 × 10^157), or as high as you think you might need.
- Then in your user-defined function, just look up `n!, k!, and (n-k)!` from the table, then calculate `(n!) / (k!) * (n-k)!`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your possible input values are going to be, it may be worth pre-computing the values and storing them in a table; retrieving `COMBIN(n, k)` would then be as easy as

```
SELECT value FROM Combin WHERE n = @n AND k = @k
```

Answer (score 0):

Precalculation does seem more sensible but a solution without.

```
declare @n int
declare @k int

SET @n = 8
SET @k = 2

SELECT 
    POWER(10.0, SUM(CASE WHEN Number > (@n - @k) THEN LOG10(Number) ELSE 0 END))/
    POWER(10.0, SUM(CASE WHEN Number <= @k THEN LOG10(Number) ELSE 0 END))
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE  type='P' AND
((Number > 0 and Number <= @k) OR (Number > (@n - @k) AND Number <= @n))
```